# UI components not getting updated in onReceiveResult after finishing service

Tags: android, service

Hi I am using service to load data from url as in this tutorial( [Background Service Tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android) ) .

I have 2 activities. 1st one for going to Activity which start service and 2nd one to start a service. When I start service from 2nd activity and waits there until the service finishes, the ui components gets updated properly.

But when I start service from 2nd Activity, finishes it and start the 2nd activity again the UI components are not getting updated when service finishes. But the fetched data is correctly coming to onReceiveResult properly only the UI views are not getting updated.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

My code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     /* Allow activity to show indeterminate progressbar */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    btnStartserv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonserv);

      /* Initialize listView */
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    /* Starting Download Service */
    mReceiver = new DownloadResultReceiver(new Handler());
    mReceiver.setReceiver(MyActivity.this);

    btnStartserv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, MyActivity.this, DownloadService.class);

             /* Send optional extras to Download IntentService */
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
            intent.putExtra("requestId", 101);

            startService(intent);



        }
    });
}
```

onReceiveResult:

```
 @Override
 public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    switch (resultCode) {
        case DownloadService.STATUS_RUNNING:

            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            break;
        case DownloadService.STATUS_FINISHED:

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Service Finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            /* Hide progress & extract result from bundle */
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            String[] results = resultData.getStringArray("result");

            System.out.println("size"+results.length);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            if(listView == null ){
                System.out.println("listview is null");

            }else{
                System.out.println("listview is NOT NULL");

            }

            btnStartserv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonserv);
            btnStartserv.setText("Service Finished!!!");

            /* Update ListView with result */
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MyActivity.this,       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            break;
        case DownloadService.STATUS_ERROR:
            /* Handle the error */
            String error = resultData.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added DownloadResultReceiver class

DownloadResultReceiver:

```
public class DownloadResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
private Receiver mReceiver;

public DownloadResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
    mReceiver = receiver;
}

public interface Receiver {
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
}

@Override
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is DownloadResultReceiver?

Comment: @pskink I,ve updated the question. Added DownloadResultReceiver  class.

Comment: inside onReceiveResult Log.d the value of mReceiver and it will explain why that happens

Comment: Hi @pskink inside onReceiveResult I put this       Log.e("mReceiver",mReceiver.toString());  and   this is the output log E/mReceiver com.example.qa_2.materialdesign.service.DownloadResultReceiver@41f66d50

Comment: @pskink My activity. public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DownloadResultReceiver.Receiver

Comment: mReceiver is DownloadResultReceiver??? not your Activity? Log.d  DownloadResultReceiver.mReceiver

Comment: and don't use misleading two mReceiver fields of different types which introduces a mess in your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82677/discussion-between-sudheesh-mohan-and-pskink).